# Mysql, change (update) all numeric values for all table

Tags: mysql

source:

constant x,y,
mysql table named 'table1'. It contains column pp.

Need change all values in table1:

```
pp_new = pp/x*y;
pp_new = round(pp_new) to 0.1.
```

For example 12.31 = 12.30, 14.56 = 14.50, 55.1245035 = 55.10

Answer (score 1):

> 12.31 = 12.30, 14.56 = 14.50, 55.1245035 = 55.10

You need to use truncate(number,decimalplaces)

```
TRUNCATE(1.25864,1)
```

this will return `1.2`

Answer (score 0):

What about something like `UPDATE table1 SET pp = round(pp/x*y)` ?